# Upgrading react-virtualized gives error: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I upgraded from react-virtualized 8.11 --> 9.1, and receiving the above error. Accounting for the docs breaking changes:

1- I'm using React version 0.15.X

2- I'm not using the CellMeasurer component.

Have any of you experienced a breaking change upgrading to react-virtualized 9 outside of the above mentioned?  I have made no other changes when upgrading.

VirtualizedTable.js

```html
import React, { Component, PropTypes }        from 'react';
import { AutoSizer, Table, Column, defaultTableRowRenderer }       from 'react-virtualized';
import classnames                             from 'classnames';
import { Input } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css';
// import '../sass/components/virtualized-table.scss';

export default class VirtualizedTable extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    schema: PropTypes.shape({
      instanceType: PropTypes.string,
      searchable: PropTypes.bool,
      skeleton: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        key: PropTypes.string,
        label: PropTypes.string,
        display: PropTypes.string,
        sortable: PropTypes.bool
      }))
    }).isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    onRowClick: PropTypes.func,
    rowClassName: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.func]),
    rowRenderFn: PropTypes.func,
    statusRenderFn: PropTypes.func,
    actionsRenderFn: PropTypes.func,
    sortBy: PropTypes.string,
    sortDirection: PropTypes.oneOf(['ASC', 'DESC']),
    maxHeight: PropTypes.number
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sortBy: 'name',
      sortDirection: 'ASC',
      tableFilter: ''
    };
    this.sort = this.sort.bind(this);
    this.onFilterChange = this.onFilterChange.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.sortBy) {
      this.setState({
        sortBy: this.props.sortBy
      });
    }
    if (this.props.sortDirection) {
      this.setState({
        sortDirection: this.props.sortDirection
      });
    }
  }
  sort({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
    if (this.state.sortBy !== sortBy) {
      this.setState({ sortBy });
    } else {
      this.setState({ sortBy, sortDirection });
    }
  }
  onFilterChange (e) {
    this.setState({ tableFilter: e.target.value });
  }
  escapeRegex (str) {
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');
  }
  render() {
    const { showFilter } = this.props;
    let sortedList = this.props.data;
    if (this.state.tableFilter) {
      let regex = new RegExp(this.escapeRegex(this.state.tableFilter), 'i');
      sortedList = this.props.data.filter(
        item => {
          let bool = false;
          for (let key in item) {
            bool = (regex.test(item[key]));
            if (bool) break;
          }
          if (bool) return item;
        }
      );
    }
    if (this.state.sortBy) {
      sortedList = sortedList.sort(
        (a, b) => typeof a[this.state.sortBy] === 'string' ?
          a[this.state.sortBy] < b[this.state.sortBy]
        :
          a[this.state.sortBy] - b[this.state.sortBy]
      );
      if (this.state.sortDirection === 'DESC') {
        sortedList.reverse();
      }
    }
    let columns = this.props.schema.skeleton.filter(item => item.display !== 'hidden');
    const rowHeight = this.props.rowHeight || 40;
    const headerHeight = this.props.headerHight || 40;
    return (
      <div className='table-container'>
        {
          (showFilter) ?
            <div className='ac-filter-container' style={{ width: '15%' }}>
              <Input
                type='text'
                onChange={this.onFilterChange.bind(this)}
                value={this.state.tableFilter}
                placeholder={this.props.filterText || 'Filter results...'}
              />
            </div>
          :
            null
        }
        <AutoSizer disableHeight>
          {({ width: autoWidth }) => {
            // Use Static width if provided - NOTE: For Testing Purposes
            const width = this.props.width || autoWidth;
            return (
              <Table
                className={classnames('table', {'collapsed': width < 1000})}
                width={width}
                height={(sortedList.length + 1) * rowHeight > this.props.maxHeight ? this.props.maxHeight : (sortedList.length + 1) * rowHeight}
                headerHeight={headerHeight}
                rowHeight={rowHeight}
                rowClassName={this.props.rowClassName}
                rowRenderer={this.props.rowRenderFn || defaultTableRowRenderer}
                rowCount={sortedList.length}
                rowGetter={({ index }) => sortedList[index]}
                sort={this.sort}
                sortBy={this.state.sortBy}
                sortDirection={this.state.sortDirection}
                onRowClick={({index}) => this.props.onRowClick(this.props.data[index])}
              >
                {
                  columns.map((column, i) => {
                    return (
                      <Column
                        key={i}
                        label={column.label}
                        dataKey={column.key}
                        disableSort={column.sortable}
                        width={width / columns.length}
                      />
                    );
                  })
                }
              </Table>
            );
          }}
        </AutoSizer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

TablContainer.js

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';

// Components
import VirtualizedTable from '../../components/VirtualizedTable3';
import {objects} from '../objects';
import shouldComponentUpdate from '../../utils/shouldComponentUpdate';


export default class TableContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.shouldComponentUpdate = shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    let schema = {
      instanceType: 'integer',
      searchable: true,
      skeleton: [{
        key: 'id',
        label: 'id',
        display: 'true',
        sotrable: true
      }, {
        key: 'name',
        label: 'name',
        display: 'true',
        sotrable: true
      }]
    };

    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>React Virtualized Table</h1>

        {
          <VirtualizedTable
            schema={schema}
            data={objects}
            onRowClick={() => console.log('U did it!')}
            sortByDefault='id'
            sortDirection='DESC'
          />
        }

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no React `0.15.X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [9.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/pull/577) call out 2 breaking changes: `CellMeasurer` and the required/supported React version:

> **Supported React versions have changed.** Previously all React 14 and 15 releases were supported. Going forward only React 15.3 and newer will be supported. This was done to drop a peer dependency on `react-addons-shallow-compare` and replace it with `React.PureComponent` as the docs suggest.

It would appear that you're not using the required React version. (NPM/Yarn should be warning you about an invalid peer dependency when you install.)